# Adding files to an array during looping of the directories

Tags: arrays, bash

this is a development of my previous question regarding the automatic collection of the selected files from the looping directories.
Here my script:

```
   #!/bin/bash
    server=$(pwd)
    results=${server}/results
    output=${server}/simulations

    date=$(date +"%m_%d_%Y")

    for sim in "$output"/* ; do
     if [[ -d $sim ]]; then
      simulation=$(basename "$sim")
      file=( "${sim}"/gromacs* )
      file_name=$(basename "${file}")
      (( ${#file[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -e $file ]] || {
        echo "ERROR: Exactly one file starting with 'gromacs' should exist" >&2
        exit 1
      }
      (cd "${sim}" && exec cp $file "${results}/${simulation}.${date}")
      echo "${file_name} from ${simulation} has been collected!"
     fi
    done
```

It creates an array within the loop and checked the duplicate files within the dirs:

```
file=( "${sim}"/gromacs* )
          file_name=$(basename "${file}")
          (( ${#file[@]} == 1 )) && [[ -e $file ]] || {
            echo "ERROR: Exactly one file starting with 'gromacs' should exist" >&2
            exit 1
          }
```

Does it possible to define this array outside the loop and append the $file to an existing array during each processing? At the end of the script when the looping is finished, I would like to print the whole array $file with the list of the files which has been collected.

Comment: Wheres your previous question?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do it like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
declare -a my_array=()

for sim in $output"/* ; do
    ...
    ... #do some conditions
    my_array+=( "$file" )
done
```